# Display a CCK field on all nodes of a site

Tags: entities

How could I programmatically take a CCK field from a particular node and display it on all nodes? The idea is to use the field as an advertisement. So, for example, a content type would have an "ad" field and a checkbox field ("display" or "don't display"). Ideally, the custom module or function would parse all nodes for the checkbox field and then randomly display an ad. Thanks for any advice. It would be for Drupal 6.x, btw.